How to update a sequential retrieval model to accept the categories as a parameter?
I followed the Tensorflow Sequential Retrieval tutorial here. The model currently accepts a list of item IDs preferred by the user like so
# create a model that takes in raw query features
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model._query_model)

# recommends movies out of the entire movies dataset.
index.index_from_dataset(
    tf.data.Dataset.zip((movies.batch(100), movies.batch(100).map(model._candidate_model)))
)

# make recommendations
scores, recommendations = index(tf.constant(["1", "2", "3"]))

I was hoping to update the model to accept an additional parameter of the categories liked by the user so the recommendations will be of items with a similar category. This is used to address the cold start problem for a new user so I could make predictions like so
scores, recommendations = index(tf.constant([""]), tf.constant(["Action", "Comedy"]))

How to do this?
